# 301 htaccess redirect specific pages with extensions to no extension

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I would like to 301 redirect a specific file with extension to no extension and the rule from htaccess file looks like this:

```
Redirect 301 /myoldfile.php /my-new-file
```

but, when I upload the htaccess file, the website redirects me to this link and it generates an error:

```
www.domain.com/my-new-file?myoldfile.php
```

So, any help about this is appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: Can you show full .htaccess in question

Comment: Here it is @anubhava  `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1

</IfModule>

Redirect 301 /myoldfile.php /my-new-file`

Answer (score 0):

Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^myoldfile\.php$ /my-new-file [L,NC,R=302]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
```

Make sure to test this after clearing your browser cache.